# Modifying GWT's user.agent when releasing

Tags: maven-2, gwt

When developing, I set the `user.agent` property to a single value, to keep compile times down. When releasing, I have a WAR file built for all user agents.

I unfortunately seem to keep forgetting to switch the property, either:

- wasting development time waiting for compiles, or
- preparing a WAR file with incomplete browser support ( not yet deployed , thankfully ).

I want to automate this, preferably using the maven-release-plugin.

Comment: Is your web site publicly accessible?  Where?

Comment: I'd like to see it for Ant, as well.

Comment: @Don Branson: no, the site is not public.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to have 2 different .gwt.xml files - one used for development and one used for production.

There is a good example on the 'Renaming modules' section of [Developer Guide/Organizing projects](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml).

The gwt.xml file used for development would inherit from the gwt.xml file used for production and set the user.agent property as well.  e.g.:

```
<module rename-to="com.foo.MyModule">
  <inherits name="com.foo.MyModule" />
  <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
</module>
```

Now, when doing development, you would use the development gwt.xml file, and when doing a production build. you would use the production gwt.xml file.

---

The easiest way to achieve this with Maven is to activate the development module using a profile. I've written in detail about this at [Maven Recipe : GWT development profile](http://rombertw.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/maven-recipe-gwt-development-profile/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it ( using GWT 1.5 ) and compilation works as expected. The only roadblock is that my Application.html still refers to Application.nocache.js, instead of ApplicationFirefox.nocache.js . Reference: http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=FAQ_CompileOnePermutation

Comment: Does the gwt.xml used for the firefox build start with
<module rename-to="Application"> ?

Comment: you're correct, this the `rename-to` was missing. I will update the answer with the maven settings I've used as well.

Answer (score 2):

Create a MavenFilteredUserAgent module that sets `user.agent` from various profiles in the pom.xml.

**MavenFilteredUserAgent.gwt.xml**

```
...
<set-property name="user.agent" value="${gwt.compile.user.agent}" />
...
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<properties>
  <!-- By default we still want all five rendering engines when none of the following profiles is explicitly specified -->
  <gwt.compile.user.agent>ie6,ie8,gecko,gecko1_8,safari,opera</gwt.compile.user.agent>
</properties>
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>gwt-firefox</id>
    <properties>
      <gwt.compile.user.agent>gecko1_8</gwt.compile.user.agent>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<!-- Add additional profiles for the browsers you want to singly support -->
....
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <!-- Put the filtered source files into a directory that later gets added to the build path -->
      <directory>src/main/java-filtered</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-sources/java</targetPath>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    </resources>
  <plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <!-- Add the filtered sources directory to the build path-->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/filtered-sources/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
...
```

Have all of your modules inherit the MavenFilteredUserAgent module.

Then you can build for just firefox like so.

`mvn install -Pgwt-firefox`

http://9mmedia.com/blog/?p=854 has more details.

Comment: For [GWT 2.1.1](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/6f2418947d7efeb9/2a6615d8b719089) you will want to remove gecko from the default list.  This should basically have the same list as the base [UserAgent module](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwt.xml)

Comment: I always get: [INFO]       [ERROR] Invalid property value '${gwt.compile.user.agent}'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML